# How to run only new Unit Test within AzureDevops pipeline

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Let's assume I have a simple Python app which has a few modules and each module has a set of tests. I've configured my Azure DevOps pipeline so that all tests are performed for each pull request to pass our quality gate.

Is it possible to configure my Azure DevOps pipeline to run tests only from Pull Request?

Comment: git diff against expected paths before running unittests and regex against the diff to extract the newly added tests and then construct suitable command line with the results ?

Comment: If the answers were useful for you, please up-vote and/or accept

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run specified test methods, you can run the following python command line in the pipeline.

```py
python -m unittest {test_module}.{test_class}.{test_method}
```

OR

```py
python -m unittest {test_class}.{test_method} path/to/test/module.py
```

See "[**unittest — Unit testing framework**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface)".

---

If you want to run the tests only when the pipeline is triggered by pull request, you can set the condition on the test task like as below.

```yaml
- task: PythonScript@0
  displayName: 'Run unittest'
  condition: startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/pull/')
  inputs:
    scriptSource: inline
    script: |
      python -m pip install unittest
      python -m unittest path/to/test/module.py
```

---

Comment: I think the op was asking about how to run only those tests that where introduced *within* that pull request ..

Comment: @SerSergious, Is there any update from you? Are the suggestions in above scenarios helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the point of continuous integration is to ensure that everything integrates, continuously. Running all the tests in the pull request is a great way to prevent breaking changes from being introduced into the target branch.

That being said, if you believe your modules can be tested independently and you can confidently map changes that occur in the pull-request to specific modules or tests, a light-weight regression could be useful. You may gain some productivity gains by speeding up the tests, but it'll come with some complexity costs that may introduce false-positives (*or additional cognitive-load for the team if you need to update and maintain this process*). That may be a fair trade off if running all the tests is expensive.

The following code can pull all changes for a specific pull request:

```yaml
- ${{ if eq( variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest') }}:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: Identify changed files
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      pwsh: true # use PowerShell Core
      script: |
        $baseUrl      = "$(System.CollectionUri)"
        $projectName  = "$(System.TeamProjectName)"
        $repoName     = "$(Build.Repository.ID)"
        $sourceBranch = "$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)"
        $targetBranch = "$(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)"

        $apiPath = "/_apis/git/repositories/$repoName/diffs/commits"
        $url = "$baseUrl/$projectName/$apiPath"

        $asciiToken = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($env:ACCESS_TOKEN)")
        $base64token = [Convert]::ToBase64String($asciiToken)

        $headers = @{
          Authorization = "Basic $base64token" 
        }

        # compare changes in the targetbranch against the sourcebranch
        $queryArgs = @{
          "api-version"  = "7.0"
          "`$skip"        = 0
          "`$top"         = 100
          baseVersion    = $targetBranch.Replace("/refs/heads/", "")
          compareVersion = $sourceBranch.Replace("/refs/heads/", "")
        }

        $complete = $false
        $results  = @()
        $skip     = 0

        do {

          $requestArgs = @{
             Uri = $url
             Method = "GET"
             Body = $queryArgs # GET Body is converted to query string args
             Headers = $headers
          }

          $result = Invoke-RestMethod @requestArgs

          $results += $result.changes |
               # only include files and exclude deletions
               Where-Object { $_.item.gitObjectType -eq "blob" -and $_.changeType -ne 'delete' } |
               ForEach-Object { $_.item.path }

          $complete = ($null -ne $result.allChangesIncluded -and `
                       $request.allChangesIncluded -eq $true)

          $skip += 100
          $queryArgs["`$skip"] = $skip
          
        } until ($complete)

        # ensure empty array or array with unique list of files
        $results = @() + ($results | Select-Object -Unique)

        # convert to single line of json
        $files = $results | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
        
        # write data as a variable that you can use in the next step
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=changedFiles]$files"

        # write to disk if you want to parse separately
        $files | Set-Content -Path "$(Build.StagingDirectory)/changedFiles.json"
          

    env:
      ACCESS_TOKEN: $(SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN)
```

Then, in the subsequent step, filter the list of files to identify the individual test files that were modified, or group the folders and locate which modules were impacted. How you perform that mapping is going to be implementation-specific. Once you know which modules or tests to run, use the approach that [@bright-ran-msft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14697693/bright-ran-msft) suggested.

Alternatively, if the modules are truly independent, consider creating separate pipelines that target the specific modules directly and then configure your Branch Policy Build Validation with a *Path Filter* that are specific to the individual modules. This approach might be easier to setup.

[image]

You could reduce the duplication of having multiple pipelines by using a template:

```yaml
# module1 - build-validation
trigger: none

steps:
- template: compile-and-test.yml
  parameters:
    moduleFolder: /path/to/module1
    testFolder: /path/to/tests/module1
```

```yaml
# module2 - build-validation
trigger: none

steps:
- template: compile-and-test.yml
  parameters:
    moduleFolder: /path/to/module2
    testFolder: /path/to/tests/module2
```

```yaml
# compile-and-test.yml
parameters:
- name: moduleFolder
  type: string

- name: testFolder
  type: string

steps:
- # steps to compile with moduleFolder as working directory
- # steps to test with testFolder as filter
```